# How can i solve vim plugins won't installing

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Hey so I was trying to make my vim better and i was just installing some plugins for vim, when I used `:PlugInstall` command it just says `No Plugin to install`.
Here is my `.vimrc` file.

```
  1 syntax on                                                                       
  2                                                                                 
  3 set noerrorbells                                                                
  4 set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4                                                     
  5 set shiftwidth=4                                                                
  6 set expandtab                                                                   
  7 set smartindent                                                                 
  8 set nu                                                                          
  9 set nowrap                                                                      
 10 set smartcase                                                                   
 11 set noswapfile                                                                  
 12 set nobackup                                                                    
 13 set undodir=~/.vim/undodir                                                      
 14 set undofile                                                                    
 15 set incsearch                                                                   
 16                                                                                 
 17 set colorcolumn=80                                                              
 18 highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=0 guibg=lightgrey                                 
 19                                                                                 
 20 call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')                                               
 21                                                                                 
 22 Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'                                                          
 23 Plug 'jremmen/vim-ripgrep'                                                      
 24 Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'                                                       
 25 Plug 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'                                               
 26 Plug 'vim-utils/vim-man'                                                        
 27 Plug 'lyuts/cim-rtags'                                                          
 28 Plug 'git@github.com:kien/ctrlp.vim.git'                                        
 29 Plug 'git@github.com:Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git'                                
 30 Plug 'mbbill/undotree'                                                          
 31                                                                                 
 32 call plug#end()
```

I am on kubuntu 20.04

Please Help, Thanks!

Comment: Check this link - 
https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9558/why-wont-vim-plug-install-my-plugins-typo

Comment: Is it possible these plug-ins are already installed? (Look inside `~/.vim/plugged`.)

Comment: Use the plugin's documentation and issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this instead:

```
call plug#begin()
   Plug 'all name'
Call plug#end()
```

Just remove the content writer in brackets and also instead of writing all the plugins together try it in batch.